# Time input type presentation in 24h format in iOS Safari

Tags: html, ios5, datetime, datepicker, mobile-safari

Since iOS 5 the time input type has been supported by Safari. However, the time is presented in AM/PM format:

[image: Datetime input type on iOS Safari]

Most European countries are using 24h format for presenting time. Is there any way to switch to 24h format? Using datetime-local with locale setting to Dutch didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using the native time picker is a good choice, however you don't have too much control on the rendering. That remains in the hands of the browser.

Instead of using the native controls, give [Mobiscroll Date & Time Scroller](http://mobiscroll.com/component/datetime) a try. You have the possibility to turn AM/PM off and work with 24HR format.

Language packs are available for localization, date format among other features. And provides a great UX for mobile devices.